# ORMLite convert timestamp to Date

Tags: android, ormlite

I have an Android project that is taking a WS provided object that includes a property that is a timestamp like this:

```
{
     "id": "106471",
     "start": "1371736194",
     "restart": "0",
     "end": "1371736194",
     "elapsed": "0",
  }
```

"start", "restart" & "end" are all timestamps in UTC. I would like ORMLite to automatically convert these into `java.util.Date` type when saving into the database. What I did was this:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "answers", daoClass=AnswerDao.class)
public class Answer extends Entity<Answer> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7486241451710750676L;

    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Integer _id;
    public static String ID = "_id";

    @DatabaseField
    @JsonProperty("end")
    private Date timestamp;
    ...
}
```

However, in the database, the timestamp is always: `1970-01-16 21:02:16.000194`. Which I guess is the epoch.

Is this at all possible or do I need to save the object as an integer and convert it each time I access it?

Comment: you are getting seconds inside your json not milliseconds. Probably your issue is due to this fact

Comment: I'd agree with that, any idea what I can do to correct it?

Comment: Multiply the number x 1000 or change the backend

Comment: I don't have control over the WS response

Comment: then you have retrieve the field as long and multiply it x 1000 before store it. I never used ORMLite, I dont know if it is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, in the database, the timestamp is always: 1970-01-16 21:02:16.000194. Which I guess is the epoch.

As @blackbelt pointed out the 1371736194 is the time in seconds not milliseconds.  I assume you are doing something like:

```
Answer answer = new Answer();
// the time field comes from a json variable
json.start = 1371736194;
answer.setTimestamp(new Date(json.start));
```

You need to multiply that number by 1000 before adding it to date.  `start` should be a long.

```
json.start *= 1000;
answer.setTimestamp(new Date(json.start));
```

If you multiple by 1000 then you should get a valid date/time of `Thu Jun 20 09:49:54 2013 EDT`.

If you need to do this automagically, then you could create your own custom data type:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/custom-data-types

However, I think you want to make your date field valid before you persist to [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/).

> Is this at all possible or do I need to save the object as an integer and convert it each time I access it?

You can save it as a `DATE_LONG` in the database which is more efficient, but you still need to do the `* 1000`. `DATE_LONG` just stores the date as long time millis.

```
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.DATE_LONG)
private Date timestamp;
```

As an aside, there that value is the number seconds since epoch, not a timestamp.  Also, to nitpick, there is a timestamp database entity type in SQL so you might consider changing the field name to `date`.

Comment: All true. I went down the custom data type path